# Learning to process files. Trying to think of a method for maintaining file pointer position

Tags: c, file

I am working on a program to store data from a text file within a structure. The goal is to perform the file processing completely within the function outside of the main. The function opens and closes the file, and when it is called by the main function it is to populate the particular structure array element is supposed to be performed upon. The test file I am using is just a text file containing 3 lines:

Gates M 60

Jobs M 55

Jane F 45

These should be populated into an array of structures when called by the function. However, when I call the function it only populates the same first line to all array elements, I believe because the file pointer resets everytime I call the function. How can I remedy this? My code is below!

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct Individual
{
    char LastName[30];
    char gender;
    unsigned int age;
};
int function(struct Individual *person)
{
    FILE *cfPtr;
    char holder[100]; 
    cfPtr = fopen("C:\\Users\\Nick\\Desktop\\myfile","r");
    fscanf(cfPtr, "%10s %c %3d", &person->LastName, &person->gender, &person->age);
    fclose(cfPtr);
}
int main(void)
{
    struct Individual person[3];
    function(&person[0]);
    function(&person[1]);
    printf("%s %c %d", person[0].LastName, person[0].gender, person[0].age);
    printf("%s %c %d", person[1].LastName, person[1].gender, person[1].age);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`FILE` already tracks position for you; you don't need to do it yourself. The problem is that you keep *re-opening* the file, which resets the location back to the beginning of the file each time.

Open it once, read multiple times, then close it. Make your function take a `FILE *` parameter.

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct Individual
{
    char LastName[30];
    char gender;
    unsigned int age;
};
int function(FILE *cfPtr, struct Individual *person)
{
    fscanf(cfPtr, "%10s %c %3d", &person->LastName, &person->gender, &person->age);
    // TODO: Check for failure
    // TODO: Return appropriate value
}
int main(void)
{
    struct Individual person[3];
    FILE *cfPtr;

    cfPtr = fopen("C:\\Users\\Nick\\Desktop\\myfile","r");
    // TODO: Check for failure 

    function(cfPtr, &person[0]);
    function(cfPtr, &person[1]);

    fclose(cfPtr);

    printf("%s %c %d", person[0].LastName, person[0].gender, person[0].age);
    printf("%s %c %d", person[1].LastName, person[1].gender, person[1].age);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is indeed a good solution. Is it possible to get the same result while opening and closing the file in the function?

Comment: Sure, look into `fseek`. But it's really inefficient to open/close the file each time.